# Core dumped with doxygen (xml + friend class)

Tags: c++, doxygen

Using doxygen 1.8.13 on Manjaro (Arch based), I'm experiencing a `segmentation fault (core dumped)` error when generating XML if `friend class` is present.

MWE:

`ex.hpp`

```
namespace growth
{
    class ManagerInterface
    {};

    class ParallelismManager : public ManagerInterface
    {};

    class RNGManager : public ManagerInterface
    {
        friend class ParallelismManager; //! friend
    };
}
```

`Doxyfile`

```
DOXYFILE_ENCODING = UTF-8
PROJECT_NAME      = MWE
INPUT             = .
INPUT_ENCODING    = UTF-8
FILE_PATTERNS     = *.hpp
GENERATE_XML      = YES
```

Turning either `GENERATE_XML = NO` or commenting `friend class ParallelismManager;` suppresses segmentation fault.

However, I'm using [breathe](http://breathe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to include the documentation to the doc of the python frontend with sphinx, which is why I need the xml... any idea how to solve this?

Comment: This is a known issue with doxygen 1.8.13 and has been fixed in the git repository awhile ago.

Comment: ok, I'll test with current master, but where did you see this bug? I could not find a thing anywhere, including on the [bug tracker](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&product=doxygen)...

Comment: In git it is revision 0f02761 with comment Bug 776791 - [1.8.13 Regression] Segfault building the breathe docs

Protected against NULL pointer of variable al; Pull request 555

Comment: Found the same recently with https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=777941 which was closed as a duplicate. I confirm it is fixed in github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as mentioned by @albert & @Marc Alff (thanks guys), this is indeed a [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=776791) specific to doxygen 1.8.13.
The MWE I posted works fine with other versions (at least 1.8.11+) and with the latest [git version](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen) (>= [0f02761](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit)).

So for anyone that might experience the same problem just upgrade your doxygen install (or downgrade until 1.8.14 is out if you don't want to compile it by hand).